# If $x$ and $y$ are positive integers such that $5x+3y=100$, what is the greatest possible value of $xy$?

Tags: optimization

I first wrote $y$ in terms of $x$. in $5x + 3y = 100$, I subtracted $5x$ from both sides to get $3y = 100 - 5x$. Therefore, $y = \frac{100 - 5x}{3}$. I substituted this into $xy$ to get $x(\frac{100 - 5x}{3}$) – You want to find the maximum value of this. This can be simplified as $\frac{-5x^2 + 100x}{3}$. I factored out a $-5$ to get $\frac{-5(x^2 - 20x)}{3}$. Completing the Square, I got $\frac{-5((x - 10)^2 - 100)}{3}$, or $\frac{-5(x - 10)^2 + 500}{3}$. The maximum value of this is when $x = 10$, since it makes $-5(x - 10)^2$ equal $0$ ($0$ is the greatest value because otherwise it would be negative). So my answer was $\boxed{\frac{500}{3}}$, but I'm pretty certain that isn't correct because the product of two positive integers can't be a fraction. Can someone help me out?
~

EDIT: I found a case where $x=11$. Then, the product is $165$. Not sure if that is the maximum, though.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, then how can the maximum value of their product, i.e., $xy$, be $\frac{500}{3}$?

Comment: $500/3$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Using modular arithmetic I'm getting $xy=125$. Is modular arithmetic allowed?

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor sure, you can use modular arithmetic if you want, but I'm pretty sure $125$ isn't the right answer because I found a case where $x=11$ and $y=15$, and their product is already $165$. I just need someone to help solve the question...

Comment: What's the minimal value of x such that $((100-5x)/3)$ is an integer?

Comment: Oh wait, what if $x=11$? Then $11-10=1$, $1^2=1$, and $(-5)(1)=-5$. $500$ minus $5$ equals $495$, and that is divisible by $3$ – you get $165$. Is that the maximum?

Comment: @chantria Note the solution is where $\lvert x - 10 \rvert$ is a minimum *and* $x$ is a positive integer solution to $5x + 3y = 100$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan |$x-10$| can't equal $0$, or the product would be a fraction. So the next minimum value would be when $x=9$ or when $x=11$.

Comment: @chantria right, I see my mistake, the correct answer is indeed 165, My solution is very similar to the one just posted by nonuser.

Comment: @chantria Yes! Thus, what do you conclude from that?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I got the answer! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chantria It's great you got the answer, and you're welcome for the help. However, one thing to be careful of though is that, in general, the solution is *not* necessarily the value of $x$ which minimizes $\lvert x - 10 \rvert$ and which has $xy$, i.e., $\frac{-5(x-10)^2+500}{3}$, is an integer. It works in your particular case, since for $x = 11$ we have $y = 15$, but it may not if, with a different example, we ended up with $x = 65$ and $xy = 169$ since then $y = \frac{13}{5}$, but this is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$3y= 100-5x\implies 3\mid 20-x$$ we have $20-x =3t$ for some integer $t$. Then $x= 20-3t$ and $y= 5t$. So we have $$xy = 5t(20-3t) \leq \max \{20\cdot 8, 15\cdot 11\}$$

(Maximum value of quadratic function is at $10\over 3$ so in the set of integers it is at $3$ or at $4$.)

Comment: Where did you get $20*8$ or $15*11$?

Comment: @IntegrateThis plug t=3 and t=4

Comment: Brilliant thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$ 5x + 3y = 100 $

Has the solution $ x = 20 - 3 t $ and $ y = 5 t $ where $ t= 1, 2, \dots $

Maximum $t $ is $\text{int}(\frac{20}{3}) = 6 $

$xy = 5 t (20 - 3 t) $

Its peak is at $\frac{1}{2} ( 0 + \frac{20}{3} ) = \frac{10}{3} $

Since this not an integer, the maximum is attained at $t = 3$ (because it closer to $\frac{10}{3}$ than $4$).  Hence, the maximum is

$ \max(xy) = 15(11) = 165 $

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, we can use [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#:%7E:text=Inequality%20of%20arithmetic%20and%20geometric%20means,-From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the). Also, notice that $3y = 5(20 -x)$, therefore $y$ is a multiple of $5$ or $xy$ is a multiple of $5$.

So, $$\frac{5x + 3y}{2} \ge \sqrt{15xy}  $$

or, $$50 \ge \sqrt{15xy}$$

By squaring both sides, we ge:$$2500 \ge 15xy$$

or $$166.67 \ge xy$$

Since $xy$ is an integer  less than $166.67$ and a multiple of $5$, so you can check that the greatest value of $xy$ is $165$.

Answer (score 0):

$We\, multiply\, \, both\, sides\, \, by\, y.\, Then\, 5xy+3y^2=100y. \, All\, we\, have\, to\, do\, is\, maximise\, 100y-3y^2.\, Using\, calculus\, we \, obtain\, y=\frac{50}{3},\, But\, this\, is\, not\, an\, integer.\, We\, \, try\, \, 16 \, which\, is\, not\, acceptable.\, \, Then\, try\, 15 \, which\, gives\, \, x=11\, y=15\, which\, \, \, are\, acceptable.\, This\:\, \,  is\, the\, maximizer.\, Thus \, max(xy)=165.\, It\, is\, very\, easy\, to\, prove\, that\, for\, y\leq 14\,\, \,  we \, either\, get\, unacceptable\, values\, or\,\, an \, xy\, smaller\, than\, 165.Also\, \, \, \, 3y=-5x+100=5k\, and\, hence\, y\, is\, a\, multiple\, of\, 5.\, It\, is \, easy\, to\, reject\, y=20\, and\, y=25\, and\, y=30.\, That \, completes\, the\, proof!!$

Comment: Tempted to vote this down for poor use of $\LaTeX$. Would you take time to consider how it ought to be used, by inspecting how other people use it? This may be doable by using "edit" on other users' answers -- although I am assuming you have the level of authorisation to be able to do that, which you may not of course. I can't remember what you can do when you only have 44 rep.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos FYI, to learn how to use the math formatting system used here, i.e., MathJax (which, as Prime Mover has pointed out, is very similar to $\LaTeX$), please see [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/602049) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/602049).

Comment: Excuse me sir but I dont see any problems in my Latex, This is a mathematical site not a typing class. About my reputation score , I just joined the club and I have other occupations too!!

Comment: Your post would be easier to read if you only enclosed the equations and mathematical expressions between dollar signs.

Comment: And it would be easier to write as well without all that $\backslash,$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while finding maxima for positive integers you will have to implement some other techniques along with the traditional ones.In your problem you get $xy=\frac{-5(x-10)^2+500}{3}$.Note that $500\equiv 2$(mod 3) and $-5\equiv 1$(mod 3).So we must have $(x-10)^2\equiv 1$(mod 3).So x-10 can't be a multiple of 3.So for minimum value x=11 and thus xy=165

Answer (score 0):

A ***not very strict*** approach using a rather standard geometric reuslt is as follows.

$5x+3y=100$ depicts a line on the plane, specifically the $y=-\frac{5}{3}x-\frac{100}{3},$ which intersects the $y-$axis on $A=(0,33,333)$ and the $x-$axis on $B=(20,0)$.

Thus the right triangle $\triangle AOB$ is formed, where $O=(0,0)$.

Now, the desired greatest possible value of $xy$ is equivalent to the area of a rectangle inside $\triangle AOB$.

But we know that the [maximum area of a rectangle inscribed in a triangle is  1/2  the area of the triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895231/maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-triangle-is-1-2-the-area-of-triangl).

By a direct computation, $E_{\triangle AOB}=333,33$. Moreover $\triangle AOB$'s perpendicular sides are of a similar length. Thus the maximum of $xy$ is expected to be near the value of $\frac{1}{2}E_{\triangle AOB}=166,67$ with $x,y$ also of approximately similar lengths.

By experimenting with pairs of $x,y$ such that $xy\approx167$, we readily observe that $(11,15)$ and $(15,11)$ are the optimal. But the second pair doesn't belong to $y=-\frac{5}{3}x-\frac{100}{3}$ and thus $(x,y)=(11,15)$ is the answer.