# Find the dimensions of the rectangle that will maximize its area if it is inscribed into a triangle.

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

[image]

I am not sure on how to start this problem. I just need a little help in starting the problem and I am certain that I can solve it, but I'm stumped on how to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: How have you used the hint they gave? That's how you start.

Comment: Find out how $x$ and $y$ are related.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how the hint helps me in this case. I know that the area of the rectangle is x * y, but how do I find out how they are related?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximizing the area of rectangle inscribed in triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636744/maximizing-the-area-of-rectangle-inscribed-in-triangle)

Comment: That problem involves using coordinates to answer the question. I don't think that could help me with this problem. I just don't get how the hint helps me find more information.

Comment: Fix $A$ to $(0,0)$.  Then we have $E(20,0)$ and $C(t,12)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the hint, we know that $x/20=(12-y)/12$ (Because the triangles are similar) $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=20-(5/3) y$

We want the maximum value Area, which is ${x}{y}\ $, or $20y-(5/3)y^2$, so we differentiate and equal to $0$.

$\frac{d}{dy}(20y-(5/3)y^2)=0 \Leftrightarrow y = 6\ $. Plugging it in the previous formula we get that the maximum value of the area is $60$ and the minimum is obviously $0$.